# Does Alpha Vantage provides real-time data for free?

Tags: programming, market-data, quantitative, tick-data

I tried a python script with alpha vantage API. But it was not giving the real-time price for GOOG, though the time was Monday, 11am ET. Does it really provides the data for free. If not, please recommend me an alternative for it.

Comment: Real-time data is generally not provided for free. An overview of data sources can be found in the link below.

Comment: I don't think so. As far, as I remember they now refer to Polygon for real-time data on US Stocks and ETFs